# css background image won't display

Tags: css, image, background-image

I have tried everything! But my background image (gif) won't show up..

My files are stored in my public_html on ftp.

I have my file linked like this in my html doc:

```
<link href="css/arena.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And I have the following lines in css:

```
body {
background-image: url('../images/2.gif'); 
}
```

I hope someone can help me out because this is really frustrating.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an error in your syntax, please try with:
`background-image: url('../images/2.gif');`

Comment: `../images/2.gif` means `2.gif` must be found in the `images` folder, which must be in the same parent folder that your `css` folder is in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in your syntax, you have to remove `:`.

`url('../images/2.gif)` instead of `url:('../images/2.gif')`

You could check [background-image property documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

Comment: Trust me I've done that already with no results unfortunately.

Comment: Well, try `background: url('../images/2.gif')`, and also check the path of your gif also it's permissions

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything. Weird thing is, if I create a folder just on my desktop doing this exact thing I'm doing right now, it does work. But on my server it doesn't.

Comment: Instead of using relative path try using url

Comment: Everything should be fine, that's the problem.
in my host folder is my arena.html and my css folder including my arena.css together with my arena.html is my images folder and within that my 2.gif. and with this setup it does work on my desktop but when I uploaded it on my server it just stopped working..

Comment: Hoow, try this `background: url('images/2.gif');` or `background-image: url('images/2.gif');`

Comment: Got it! It was permissions indeed. Thanks all for replying and helping out.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved. It had to do with the permissions. Thanks y'all for helping out, greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Could you explain a bit further how you managed to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Changing the path to include ../img/bgheader.jpg fixed it.